# How can I use elasticsearch search API to return a token with whitespace

Tags: elasticsearch

As title

I'm newbie to the elasticsearch-7.4.2.
I want to use search API to get some token with whitespace.

something like

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_analyze?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "analyzer" : "standard",
    "text": "agnes b"
}
'
```

Return

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "agnes",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "b",
      "start_offset" : 6,
      "end_offset" : 7,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get token "agnes b"
How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `keyword` analyzer instead of the `standard` one:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_analyze?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "analyzer" : "keyword",           <-- change this
    "text": "agnes b"
}
'
```

Comment: Feel free to create a new question and reference it from here